# Set MaximumThreshold Per List Group

Tags: 2013, workflow, javascript, infopath, custom-list

Not sure if this possible, but I am going to give it a try.  I have a custom list with an InfoPath as form.  In the list I have it grouped by 'Status'.  The status are "High", "Low", "Closed".  I have the count on for each group too.  What I want to do is when the count for each group reaches 11 the user will not be able to select save the form.  The image shows 11 is met at Status - High. So no user should be able to save a form if "High" is selected as the status.

Can this be done in SharePoint?  Can this be done in the InfoPath 2013 form as a rule?  If this can be done in SharePoint or InfoPath can someone guide me in the right direction?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is tricky. In theory, you could build a workflow that checks the number and takes some action, but workflows run after the item is saved, so that's out.

Another possibility is to create a data connection from infopath that's filtered to only return "high" items and use the count() function to see how many items you have. then, configure the submit rules to only allow submits when the count is appropriate. This solution could have issues when multiple people submit the form at the same time, but perhaps that's a low risk scenario?

Another possibility is to write a custom event handler. This assumes that you're running SP on-prem and not O365. This would be the best scenario for functionality, but of course has the significant downside of involving code.

Instructions for getting the count of items in a sharepoint list are [here](https://www.spums.be/count-listitems-in-infopath/)